# Joomla constant to current template path

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I develop a custom module and I need this module to show some pictures choosen in backend. So... I declare a parameter with type "imagelist" in my module xml file.

```
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="advanced">
            <field
                name="project1-image"
                type="imagelist"
                directory="???\images"
                label="..."
                description="..." />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
```

The problem is "images" dir located in some Joomla template. Is there maybe some constant like "JPATH_COMPONENT" or "JPATH_BASE" pointing to currently applied template to site? Or I need force site admin to write filename and find it in php file of my module, this seems like a bad solution.

Thanks in advance, Andrey!

Comment: Try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Why do you use template's images folder when you can use /images in Joomla root?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <field name="myimage" type="imagelist" default="" 
label="Select an image" description="" directory="images" exclude="" stripext="" />
```

directory (optional) is the filesystem path to the directory containing the image files to be listed. If omitted the directory given by `JPATH_ROOT` is assumed.

You can also use `<field name="myimage" type="media" directory="stories" />`
This will open the media manager with the directory `/images/stories/` already selected.